# IOS 8 - Navigation bar buttons issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, subview

My app has simple viewControll(XIB, no storyboard) with 6 sub views
When user click on buttons sub view bring  in front of current view (by using call [self.view bringSubviewToFront:usageView];)
App working fine on IOS 6 and 7 but I facing issue on IOS 8.
When I click on buttons for bring sub view in front sub view come up with like below image

[image]

Navigation bar right side buttons "Done" show improper, its hide only in iOS 8

Please help me for this issue I am new in IOS development. If your required any more information please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in viewDidLoad method of this viewController and customise it like you want

```
 UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_A.png"];
UIImage *backButtonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_B.png"];

UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[backButton setImage:backButtonImage
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backButton setImage:backButtonImage1
            forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[backButton setImage:backButtonImage1
            forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 45);

[backButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(goBack)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

With frame you can show the button where you want.

Comment: I have putted your code but button cant appear. I replaced image name with my exiting image.

Comment: "Done" Button in XIB and I just bounded with view control

Comment: Try to remove it from xib and add it programmatically.

Comment: I tried but not showing button. I deleted button from xib and your code added to viewdidload

Comment: Did you "play" with sizes of frame??

Comment: I mean the frame of the button that exists above in the code. If you did not change this give a try and play a little with the frame of the button.